# Android. NDK. OpenGLES2. Mysteriously not working drawing

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

Here is some mysteriously problem.

```
// There are in global space
VertexBufferGLES2 vb(true);
IndexBufferGLES2 ib(true);
...
// Initialization
vb.Create(sizeof(tris), tris, USAGE_STATIC_);
ib.Create(sizeof(indices), indices, USAGE_STATIC);
...
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb.GetVertexBufferGLES2());
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ib.GetIndexBufferGLES2());
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (GLvoid *)0);
```

In such case all works perfectly, but with code below nothing is drawing.

```
// There are in global space
VertexBufferGLES2 *vb = NULL;
IndexBufferGLES2 *ib = NULL;
...
// Initialization
vb = new VertexBufferGLES2(true);
ib = new IndexBufferGLES2(true);

vb->Create(sizeof(tris), tris, USAGE_STATIC_);
ib->Create(sizeof(indices), indices, USAGE_STATIC);
...
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb->GetVertexBufferGLES2());
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ib->GetIndexBufferGLES2());
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (GLvoid *)0);
...
delete vb;
delete ib;
```

All other code is identical. Differs only this two piece of code.
I've been three days searcing for fix, but nothing is found, because of this code is so obviosly and logically identical, must be...

The problem is solved: in function "create" i use member variable(enum) before assign to it value from "create" function params. In first case compiler initialize this variable to 0 that is proper(because this is first enum value) for code and all was working normally. In second case compiler doesn't initialize variable because of class was created on heap and in it variable was garbage.

My mistake was in this code:

```
int VertexBufferGLES2::Create(int size, void *data, USAGE_ usage)
{
    if (size == 0) return -1;

    Delete();

    m_size = size;

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buffer);
    // The function GetGLES2Usage() is mapping my m_usage enum to
    // OpenGL ES 2 enum
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GetGLES2Usage());
    // but the value to m_usage i assign here. Moving up (to above   
    // glBufferData line) this code line solves the problem  
    m_usage = usage;

    if (m_useCache) CacheData(size, data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can include code, but for what? Problem is solved and i don't need help anymore. Maybe is there some button "Close answer"? (I'm new on stackoverflow)

Comment: You can answer your own question -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

The lines

```
VertexBufferGLES2 vb = NULL;
IndexBufferGLES2 ib = NULL;
```

look suspicious, maybe you should try

```
VertexBufferGLES2* vb = NULL;
IndexBufferGLES2* ib = NULL;
```

Comment: I'm sorry. That is misprint. I have fixed. Thank you for note